# Troubleshooting accounts when passwords are hashed

Tags: security, passwords

We currently store passwords in plain text.  One of the reasons is that it is easier to troubleshoot account specific issues when we can lookup a password and log into the account.  This has always bothered me, but if we start hashing passwords, what would be the best way to troubleshoot account specific issues?  How is this normally handled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either via impersonation or password reset. For impersonation, you allow users with a certain permission to specify a user they will impersonate. Then they can log in with their own password and use the system as the other user. The other option is to simply change the user's password through an admin tool when you need access, and then do a password reset once you're done, and they then can create their personal password again.